# Automate a command in Visual Studio Immediate Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I want to know the caller controller/action of a View (in debug mode), I use two following commands in Visual Studio Immediate Window.

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue 
@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue
```

Is there any way to automate this process instead of typing them in Immediate Window all the time? or any better way to find out the Caller?

**Update:**

By automating I mean adding a shortcut key to execute this command or adding a Menu Item to the Context Menu.

I know that there is no need to type and I can hit up arrow key. However, I need a more robust method.

Comment: if you use the 'up arrow' inside the 'Immediate Window' then the last instrcution will appear for you, you just then need to press the  'enter' key.

Answer (score 0):

1- if you use the 'up arrow' inside the 'Immediate Window' then the last instrcution will appear for you, you just then need to press the 'enter' key to execute it.

2- Why not to use the 'watch' panel, it could save this for you, and it will update whenever the value has changed

[image]